# Matrix reduction

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Here's the setup:

$A$ is an $n\times n$ matrix over $\mathbb{Z}$. Futher let $\sigma$ be the set of eigenvalues of $A$ (which may contain multiplicities).

Question:

Is there a general way of reducing the matrix $A$, to say matrix $A'$, such that $\sigma' = \sigma - \{0\}$, i.e., $A'$ is an $m \times m$ matrix ($m \leq n$) where $A'$ has the same set of non-zero eigenvalues as $A$, and $n - m$ is the number of zero eigenvalues of $A$?

I am wondering if one can find invertible matrices $P$ and $Q$ such that $A' = PAQ$ (or something like this). Thanks!

Edit:

Oops, let $B := \begin{bmatrix} A' & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$ be a block matrix, and so what I was looking for is something like $B = PAQ$.

Answer (score 1):

Certainly your last statement wouldn't work as if $P$ and $Q$ are to be invertible, then $P, A, Q$ and hence $A'$ all have the same size.

Regarding the original question, it depends what other properties you'd like your new matrix to have. If it just needs to have the same non-zero eigenvalues then you can trivially construct such a matrix but it would be pretty unrelated to $A$. Surely you'd want the same eigenspaces too, but for this to happen you can't reduce the size of $A$ as this reduces the size of the space $A$ acts on. Hence my answer would be no.

Comment: I meant $B$ not $A'$. I already edited it, thanks!